# iPhone iOS open source gyroscope based spherical coordinate system viewer, like 360 panorama or tour wrist

Tags: objective-c, ios5, trigonometry, iphone-4, panoramas

I'm looking for an iPhone based, preferably iOS5 with ARC project that uses the iPhone4's gyro to look around in spherical coordinate system. The phone is at the center of a sphere, and by looking at the sensor output, it can understand where the camera is pointing in spherical coordinates.

**I'm not sure if what I'm thinking of can be accomplished with iOS5 CMAttitude which blends sensors of iPhone4 can it?**

I intend to use the project to control a robotic turret and make it be able to "look" at a particular point within a spherical coordinate system.

What comes to mind is that a 360 panorama or a tour wrist like app would be a good starting point for such a project. **Is there something that is similar, open source and uses native iOS Core Motion framework?**

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I am also looking for a solution  for this... I want to make a panoramic camera.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to license the TourWrist technology, please let me know. For example, we license the TourWrist capture and viewer APIs/SDKs.

Dan Smigrod
via: support@TourWrist.com